# Getting 'undeclared variables' error when accessing the value of a variable between different folders

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include

I’m working on a project that is implemented using C++ and running on Linux, I am trying to access certain values from different files in different folders and I tried several solutions but none of them help.

I have a file, let’s called file1.cpp and file1.h inside a folder called ‘folderA’ 
And I have another file let’s called file2.cpp and file2.h inside 2 folders called folderB / folderBB.

In file2.cpp, it has the value of the parameter that I want to send or access from file1.cpp
file2.cpp

```
    Include”file2.h”
    .
    .
    .
    for(…)
    Test++;   // it is defined in file2.h
```

Now what I want is to access the value of “Test” from file1.cpp to work on it. I used Makefile to compile all my files in this project. So I make a link between these two files without errors as follows:

file1.cpp: folderB / folderBB/file2.h
file2.cpp: folderA/file1.h

The problem is that when I put (include”file2.h”) inside file1.cpp or file1.h, I got lots of errors of undeclared variables that are declared in file2.h. I tried to use” extern keyword” but I got same previous error + “storage class specified”. So would you please help me to find a solution for this problem, please?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

how Test variable is declared? if is static in file2.h it will be file resident and not visible in other files